# Add style to another element on focus on the input field

Tags: html, css

I have a html structure :

```
<div class="floating-labels">
   <div class="form-group focused">
      <span class="select2 select2-container">
         <span class="selection">
            <span class="select2-selection">
                <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
                    <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
                        <input class="select2-search__field" type="search"> // on focus here
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </span>
         </span>
         <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </span>
       <span class="bar"></span> // change style here                        
    </div>                                    
 </div>
```

Here I want to add style **width: 50%;** to the class **.bar** when i focus on input box with class **.select2-search__field** through css.

I tried like this

```
 .floating-labels > .focused > .select2-search__field:focus ~ .floating-labels > .focused > bar:after {
       width: 50%;
  }
```

But it didnt worked.

Comment: This is not proper HTML markup, the `span`s are not closed and there is a opening `div` tag on the second to last line. Your IDE should warn you about these things.

Also you left out some key CSS that will help anyone assist you. The styles for the bar and it's pseudo `:after` element should be included at the very least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to accomplish this without using Javascript then there is really only one option with your HTML structure, `focus-within` you can find more information on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within), the [support](https://caniuse.com/?search=focus-within) is now very good in modern browsers.

Check for `focus-within` on the `.select2` span and select the next `.bar` element's `:after` and apply your styles there. If you need to support IE there are polyfills but then you'd be using Javascript either way so you might as well just use Javascript to manipulate your styles.

```css
.select2:focus-within + .bar:after {
  width: 50%
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
}

.bar:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s ease
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-labels">
  <div class="form-group focused">
    <span class="select2 select2-container">
         <span class="selection">
            <span class="select2-selection">
                <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
                    <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
                        <input class="select2-search__field" type="search">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```